# need to stop published c sharp application downloading framework 4.0 on installation

Tags: msbuild, publish

I built an application in c#. I published it using the publish option in the visual studio 2010 IDE. I have not used anything fancy in it, its a simple app with a couple of table layout panels. But each time i install it somewhere the app is trying to download the full framework 4.0 in which ever machine i install it.This is very irritating especially since i have not done anything very fancy here. Kindly help me on this problem.

Also i am open to anyother build tools to package my application and install it easily anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit which prerequisites are set to install when your application is installed by going to the projects properties, going to the publish tab and selecting "Prerequisites".

[image]

Comment: found this out by myself later. I forgot that i even asked this question.